# $L$ is a linear map. Show that the dimension of $ker(L) = n-1$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space, and $L: V \to \mathbb{R}$ be a linear map.  $L(s*\vec{v_1} + t*\vec{v_2})= sL(\vec{v_1}) + tL(\vec{v_2})$, for any $s,t \in \mathbb{R}$ and any $\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2} \in V$.

Show that the dimension of $ker(L)= n-1$

I know that the definition of $ker(L)= {v \in V | L(v) = 0}$

I'm not fully grasping what the mapping is doing. If you take a linear combination of two vectors, it is the same as multiplying each individual linear map by the constants, then adding? I don't understand what $sL(v_1) + tL(v_2)$ is, since doesn't $L$ need two vectors? $( L(s*v1 + t*v2) )$

Comment: Use the rank nullity theorem.

Comment: The claim above is true **iff** the map $\;L\;$ is non-zero, **iff** it is onto...

Comment: What you ask about is just the definition of *linear* map, which is what $\;L\;$ is.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add "given that ker(L) us a linear subspace of V, and assuming L is a non-zero map"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$L$ doesn't need two vectors! It's a function that maps a vector from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}$. But you can add these two vectors to produce a third vector that $L$ sends to $\mathbb{R}$.

In other words, let $\vec{v_3}=s\vec{v_1}+t\vec{v_2}$. Then $L(s\vec{v_1}+t\vec{v_2})=L(\vec{v_3})=L(s\vec{v_1})+L(t\vec{v_2})$. This is simply the definition of a linear map.

Here's the intuition behind your question: Recall that the kernel of a map is the degree to which it fails to be bijective. $L$ sends a vector of $n$ dimensions to a one-dimensional quantity $\mathbb{R}$. The vector loses $n-1$ of its dimensions when $L$ sends it from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so its kernel is of dimension $n-1$.

Comment: Sorry, edited my mistake. I guess the point is that it is *not* a bilinear operator, so it does not require two vectors in the domain, as the OP claimed!

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not sure what you mean by "the degree to which it fails to be bijective." My understanding of kernel is that it is the set of vectors which equal 0 when mapped. If there are 10 vectors in V, why can't all of them be 0 when mapped? Because of the restriction that L is a non-zero map? Then why is the dimension exactly n-1? Why can't it be something else? Why does at least one of the elements have to produce 0?

Comment: They can't all be $0$ when mapped because $\mathrm{L}$ is a non-zero map, that is correct. When he says "the degree to which it fails to be bijective" he means when $L(\mathrm{u}) = L(\mathrm{v})$ for linearly independent $\mathrm{u}$ and $\mathrm{v}$. This is because $L$ is clearly not a bijection in this instance and $L(\mathrm{u}) - L(\mathrm{v}) = 0 = L(\mathrm{u} - \mathrm{v}) = 0$ so $\mathrm{u} - \mathrm{v} \in \operatorname{Ker(\operatorname{L})}$.